# floating point exception with a postfix calculator

Tags: c, floating-point-exceptions

This is my attempt to code a postfix calculator using a stack. I have two functions pop and push and  the variable l indicate the last element. When executed with the terminal, it should be like this:

./postfix 3 2 +
5

instead I get the error : floating point exception.

I cannot find where the error comes from.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define STACK_SIZE_MAX 1024

int tab[1024] = {};
int l = 0; // last element to be used

void push(int x)
{
    tab[l] = x;
    l++;
}

int pop()
{
    int x = tab[l-1];
    l--;
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // reading arguments one by one
    int i =1;
    for(i; i < argc; i++){
        switch(*(argv[i]))
        {
        case '+':
        {
      
            int x = pop();
            int y = pop();
            int s = x + y;

            push(s);
        }
        case '-':
        {
     
            int x = pop();
            int y = pop();
            int s = x - y;
            push(s);
        }
        case '*':
        {
      
            int x = pop();
            int y = pop();
            int s = x * y;
            push(s);
        }
        case '/':
        {
      
            int x = pop();
            int y = pop();
            int s = x / y;
            push(s);
        }
        default:
            // if it is a number we push it to the stack
            push(atoi(argv[i]));
            break;
        }
    }
    // display the result
    printf("the result is  : %d ",tab[0]);
}
```

Comment: You're missing `break` statements at the end of each `case`.

Comment: It worked. I didn't know this, my thanks.